# Java Able to perform identity insert in one table but not in another

Tags: sql-server, spring

I'm copying a data from one table of another database and inserting it into another database with same table.
I have written a java code to do this job, I have two tables Container_Detail and Remote_Event2.
Both the tables contains identity column.
In java code I'm setting identity insert on whenever I'm going to insert data into a table and after that in finally block I'm setting identity insert off.
Same java code is working fine for Container_Detail table but for Remote_Event table I'm getting following error :

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Remote_Event2' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Following are the logs of `Container_Detail` table (in which my code is working fine) :

> 2016-02-22 13:43:11 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-5] JdbcTemplate:533 -
>   Executing SQL update [SET IDENTITY_INSERT Container_Detail ON]
>   2016-02-22 13:43:11 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-5] JdbcTemplate:540 -
>   SQL update affected -1 rows 2016-02-22 13:43:11 DEBUG 
>   [http-nio-8089-exec-5] JdbcTemplate:533 - Executing SQL update [INSERT
>   INTO Container_Detail
>   (detail_id,container_id,item_id,quantity,attribute_id,inventory_status,tenant_id,attribute_group,seqnum)
>   VALUES
>   ('1','00007712120036947807','Dummy_Item','1','ATTR00000000258','A','NWC','','0')]
>   2016-02-22 13:43:12 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-5] JdbcTemplate:540 -
>   SQL update affected 1 rows 2016-02-22 13:43:12 DEBUG 
>   [http-nio-8089-exec-5] JdbcTemplate:533 - Executing SQL update [SET
>   IDENTITY_INSERT Container_Detail OFF]

Following are the logs of `Remote_Event2` table in which I'm getting error :

> 2016-02-22 14:01:10 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-1] JdbcTemplate:533 -
>   Executing SQL update [SET IDENTITY_INSERT Remote_Event2 ON] 2016-02-22
>   14:01:11 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-1] JdbcTemplate:540 - SQL update
>   affected -1 rows 2016-02-22 14:01:11 DEBUG  [http-nio-8089-exec-1]
>   JdbcTemplate:533 - Executing SQL update [INSERT INTO Remote_Event2
>   (event_id,event_type,tenant_id,geoloc_id,event_status,retry_count,last_updt_user,response_code,response_msg,create_dte,process_start_dte,process_end_dte)
>   VALUES
>   ('161','CloseDelivery','NWC','CATHO','PENDING','1','anjani','0','Success','2015-12-21
>   13:25:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0')]
>   2016-02-22 14:01:12 ERROR  [http-nio-8089-exec-1] ExceptionUtil:14 -
>   Exception Occurred:
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   StatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO Remote_Event2
>   (event_id,event_type,tenant_id,geoloc_id,event_status,retry_count,last_updt_user,response_code,response_msg,create_dte,process_start_dte,process_end_dte)
>   VALUES
>   ('161','CloseDelivery','NWC','CATHO','PENDING','1','anjani','0','Success','2015-12-21
>   13:25:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0')]; Cannot
>   insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Remote_Event2'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert
>   explicit value for identity column in table 'Remote_Event2' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF., UUID:
>   7a940d15-d842-4b02-be44-8c8d66b57c65 2016-02-22 14:01:12 ERROR 
>   [http-nio-8089-exec-1] ExceptionUtil:15 -
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   StatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO Remote_Event2
>   (event_id,event_type,tenant_id,geoloc_id,event_status,retry_count,last_updt_user,response_code,response_msg,create_dte,process_start_dte,process_end_dte)
>   VALUES
>   ('161','CloseDelivery','NWC','CATHO','PENDING','1','anjani','0','Success','2015-12-21
>   13:25:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0','2015-12-21 20:18:00.0')]; Cannot
>   insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Remote_Event2'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert
>   explicit value for identity column in table 'Remote_Event2' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. 2016-02-22 14:01:14 DEBUG 
>   [http-nio-8089-exec-1] JdbcTemplate:533 - Executing SQL update [SET
>   IDENTITY_INSERT Remote_Event2 OFF] 2016-02-22 14:01:14 DEBUG 
>   [http-nio-8089-exec-1] JdbcTemplate:540 - SQL update affected -1 rows

Please note I'm using SQL Server and Spring JDBC.
Please suggest what to do and where's the actual problem?

EDIT:

I'm using following SQL Queries :

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TABLE@ ON

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TABLE@ OFF

I'm passing the table name in a query through java code :

```
@Override
public void setIdentityInsertOn(String tableName, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase) throws WMSLiteDAOException {
    String sqlQuery = CommonUtility.fetchSqlQuery(LookupSQLQueries.SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_ON);
    sqlQuery = CommonUtility.generateDynamicQueryForCustomTable(sqlQuery, tableName, "", "", null);
    maintenanceDAO.updateData(sqlQuery, jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase);
}
@Override
public void setIdentityInsertOff(String tableName, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase) throws WMSLiteDAOException {
    String sqlQuery = CommonUtility.fetchSqlQuery(LookupSQLQueries.SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_OFF);
    sqlQuery = CommonUtility.generateDynamicQueryForCustomTable(sqlQuery, tableName, "", "", null);
    maintenanceDAO.updateData(sqlQuery, jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase);
}
```

Code which is generating query (its working fine checked while debugging) :

```
public static String generateDynamicQueryForCustomTable(String sqlQuery, String tableName, String primaryKey, String values, Map<String, String> rowData){
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@TABLE@", tableName);
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@PRIMARYKEY@", primaryKey);
    if(values != null && !values.isEmpty()){

        values = values.replaceAll(" ", "");
        values=values.replaceAll("^|$", "'").replaceAll(",", "','"); 

        }
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@VALUES@", values);
    if(sqlQuery.contains("@COLUMN_VALUES@")){
        StringBuilder columnNames = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder columnValues = new StringBuilder();
        for(String currentKey : rowData.keySet()){
            columnNames = columnNames.append(currentKey+",");
            columnValues = columnValues.append("'"+rowData.get(currentKey)+"',");
        }
        columnNames = columnNames.replace(columnNames.length() - 1, columnNames.length(), "");
        columnValues = columnValues.replace(columnValues.length() - 1, columnValues.length(), "");
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@COLUMN_NAMES@", columnNames);
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@COLUMN_VALUES@", columnValues);
    }
    return sqlQuery;
}
```

Comment: It litterally tells you in the error. You are trying to insert an identity column value, but you havent turned identity insert on.... Instead of posting this monster error, post the code you are using to insert the data, both java and SQL

Comment: @Takarii Check the logs first please I have executed the query to set identity insert on in that table still it asks me to set it on. Next time please read carefully before commenting.

Comment: The logs EXPLICITLY state that identity insert is off in Remote_Event2. Post your SQL code, otherwise no further help can be given.

Comment: SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_ON = SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TABLE@ ON

SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_OFF = SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TABLE@ OFF

These are the queries in which I'm passing table name explicitly through a java method below :

 public void setIdentityInsertOff(String tableName, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase) throws WMSLiteDAOException {
  String sqlQuery = CommonUtility.fetchSqlQuery(LookupSQLQueries.SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_OFF);
  sqlQuery = CommonUtility.generateDynamicQueryForCustomTable(sqlQuery, tableName, "", "", null);
  maintenanceDAO.updateData(sqlQuery, jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase);
 }

Comment: public void setIdentityInsertOn(String tableName, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase) throws WMSLiteDAOException {
  String sqlQuery = CommonUtility.fetchSqlQuery(LookupSQLQueries.SET_IDENDTITY_INSERT_ON);
  sqlQuery = CommonUtility.generateDynamicQueryForCustomTable(sqlQuery, tableName, "", "", null);
  maintenanceDAO.updateData(sqlQuery, jdbcTemplateArchiveDatabase);
 }

Comment: Can you update your question with these details?

Comment: updated, any solution?

Comment: For debugging purposes, print the exact query that is being submitted to the DB into the console and review it. I have a feeling it lies in that your query isn't being built the way you think it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is transaction related. You must haven't implemented transaction due to which every sql query java executing is in separate session therefore you are not able to set identity insert on for the session in which you are executing insert query.

Implement AOP Transaction by annotating in a following way :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

After implementing transaction there will be only one session in current transaction through which all the queries will execute.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @Siddharth